# Compass add compact() to css files

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

When I use `box-shadow` Compass mixin CSS, the output is not correct

Input:

```
.my-class 
   +box-shadow(0 0 1px 1px #b1b1b1)
```

Output:

```
.my-class {
    -moz-box-shadow: compact(0 0 1px 1px #b1b1b1, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
}
```

The correct output should be like http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/box_shadow/

```
.my-class {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #b1b1b1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Color should be the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your compass gem might not have been installed correctly, since the "compact" function is not standard SASS, but added by compass.

Answer (score 1):

[“Compact” function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649016/compact-function-in-bourbon-with-sass-not-called)

I added this function into included file _css3.scss and everything working.