# "Compact" function in Bourbon with SASS not called

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem using mixins included in Bourbon.
When this mixin uses the "compact" function of Bourbon, it just compile it into the css without using it.
Here is a screenshot of the rendred CSS for a box-shadow :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF1JB.png

I use it on a non-static site, with the latest Sass version. I use Codekit to compile.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41957672/compass-box-shadow-mixin-returns-invalid-property-value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok so after diving a bit deeper here is how I fixed it.

This problem is probably being caused because of this commit:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/commit/ac07c990c0d0fe16f4c455490c9a9fdff7fe27af

The **compact** function has been rewritten in Ruby to better integrate with Rails. 
Initially I just copy pasted the 'stylesheet' folder from the repo. And thats when I started false sytax.

I fixed the error by reading the instructions :) - the instruction on how to install it in Rails and then it worked.

In your case, idk if they have a codekit implementation but I believe you can fix it by adding the following code:

```
@function compact($var-1,        $var-2: false,
                  $var-3: false, $var-4: false,
                  $var-5: false, $var-6: false,
                  $var-7: false, $var-8: false,
                  $var-9: false, $var-10: false) {
  $full: $var-1;
  $vars: $var-2, $var-3, $var-4, $var-5,
         $var-6, $var-7, $var-8, $var-9, $var-10;

  @each $var in $vars {
    @if $var {
      $full: $full, $var;
    }
  }
  @return $full;
}
```

*(I got the code from the repo)*

in a file name _function.scss inside your addons folder and reference it in _bourbon.scss. And that should fix your problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue when running assets:precompile.  I used your solution, but I had to add $var-11 to the above lists.  Thanks for the apt solution.

Comment: This saved my day. Thanks!