# compact() issue with compass

Tags: sass, compass-sass, fuelphp

I have just started using compass and need to use it in a Fuel project so running compass create is not viable for me.

I have imported the files manually but it is putting `compact()` over all my mixins making them not work.

I have reinstalled the gem and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you are seeing. Can you please provide examples?

Comment: Yeah I'm a little confused what exactly you're seeing. A code sample would be really helpful.

Comment: @j0k, the original word "mixins" is correct, not "mixing". The OP is referring to [Sass Mixins](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the likely problem is that the compact() function is defined in Ruby by Compass, so is not being included. The easiest solution is to reimplement the function in Sass.

Somebody else posted the appropriate solution here: ["Compact" function in Bourbon with SASS not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649016/compact-function-in-bourbon-with-sass-not-called)