# Library for `compact` not loaded

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

When I try to use `linear-gradient` with bourbon:

```
@include linear-gradient(#8080a0, #606090);
```

I get this:

```
background-color: #8080A0;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(100%, compact(#8080A0, #606090, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, compact(#8080A0, #606090, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, compact(#8080A0, #606090, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, compact(#8080A0, #606090, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, compact(#8080A0, #606090, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
background-image: linear-gradient(top, compact(#8080A0, #606090, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
```

which seems to indicate that `compact()` is not called. It is defined in a separate file in a place called `lib/bourbon/sass_extensions/functions/compact.rb`. How can I  get that loaded?

**Solved**

The problem seemed to be with bourbon itself. I was using version 2.1.3, which had the problem. The authors have been updating it in these few days, and they added a new version 3.0.1, which is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752227/44816) helpful for getting your compact function working?

**Original Answer to Original Question** (for posterity)

`compact()` is not valid CSS. Your generated CSS contains multiple references and Chrome disregards rules it doesn't know how to interpret.

Comment: I just realized that. It seems that `compact()` is defined in a separate file in a place called `lib/bourbon/sass_extensions/functions/compact.rb`. Do you know how to get that loaded?

Comment: It turned out that the authors of bourbon was changing it these few days. I updated to the newest one, and it works now.