# Compass "box-shadow" mixin returns Invalid property value

Tags: sass, webpack, compass, node-sass, sass-loader

For some reason `box-shadow` mixin returns value that is considered Invalid by browser. Why does it happen? How to fix?

In my `.scss`:

```
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow";

@include box-shadow(0px 1px 5px 1px #c4c3c3);
```

Returns this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: compact(0px 1px 5px 1px #c4c3c3, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
-moz-box-shadow: compact(0px 1px 5px 1px #c4c3c3, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
box-shadow: compact(0px 1px 5px 1px #c4c3c3, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
```

[image: Compass box-shadow invalid return]

I use compass with webpack's `sass` and `css` loaders. This is what is returned in a `<script>` tag:

[image]

**UPD**:

It looks like this is [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) issue. `sass-loader` is using `node-sass` and `node-sass` is not compatible with Compass. https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1004

Comment: The value that is being output is indeed wrong. The `box-shadow` property doesn't take anything like `compact` etc etc. But when I try your code at sassmeister.com, the output is a very valid code that is completely different from the output given here.

Comment: The [`box-shadow` mixin](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_shadow/) is using some helper functions which in turn are returning the output of some `compact` function. Looks like something somewhere in this chain is failing (or) some extra includes/imports are missing etc. I can't find out the exact problem and so just leaving this info here as a comment to help others with the analysis.

Comment: This should help you too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649016/compact-function-in-bourbon-with-sass-not-called

Answer (score 0):

Like you I was importing box shadow in the same way `@import "compass/css3/box-shadow";` and having the same problem.

This should work right? The why, I can't answer other than to say we updated out SASS compiler from Compass to gulp-sass which I believe is based off of node-sass. (Following the comments node-sass seems to be involved. I prefer to just import what I need like you). I found as [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) did that it seems the chain is failing.

**To resolve this I updated my import statement to** `@import "compass/css3";` **and it worked as expected**. This will get you going but may not be ideal depending on your situtation.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but then I realized that the sass generated version of the css was not including the "px" for my values.

I had to add the px to each value I was setting. Because it needs to be next to the number, i.e. 8px, I had to use the interpolation syntax shown below.

```
@mixin halo($halo-color: $gray-base, $halo-width: 8) {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 #{$halo-width}px $halo-color;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 #{$halo-width}px $halo-color;
    box-shadow: 0 0 #{$halo-width}px $halo-color;
}
```