# gulp-sass warping background-images with compact

Tags: css, gulp, gulp-sass

I am using gulp tool and gulp-sass to compile scss file.
the relevant gulp file code:

```js
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

function styles() {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass.sync({includePaths: ['app/bower_components','node_modules'],
                      outputStyle: 'expanded'
                    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'));
};
```

this generate file main.css with all relevant css, the only problem is that for background-images tag I get this:

```css
background-image: -owg(compact(linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e1e1e1), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: -webkit(compact(linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e1e1e1), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: -moz(compact(linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e1e1e1), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: -o(compact(linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e1e1e1), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: compact(linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #e1e1e1), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
```

I want to understand where it comes from and how do I remove it since Chrome gives me this error: Invalid property value.

I know I need to remove it because when I go to the inspection tools in chrome and remove the 'compact', the right colour appears.

I tried to search on the web but nothing worked for me.
I tried to use gulp-compass but I get an error in Ruby, I tried gulp-for-compass but this didn't work eighter.
I tried to play with the outputStyle option but it is not related.

can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752227/14327518

I created a new file name _functions and I copy-paste:

```
    @function compact($var-1,        $var-2: false,
                  $var-3: false, $var-4: false,
                  $var-5: false, $var-6: false,
                  $var-7: false, $var-8: false,
                  $var-9: false, $var-10: false) {
  $full: $var-1;
  $vars: $var-2, $var-3, $var-4, $var-5,
         $var-6, $var-7, $var-8, $var-9, $var-10;

  @each $var in $vars {
    @if $var {
      $full: $full, $var;
    }
  }
  @return $full;
}
```

then I imported this file in my main.scss before the imports of compass-mixins libraries

the result main.css was as expected for example:

```
line {
  stroke: #a4a4a4;
  stroke-width: 2;
  -webkit-transition: stroke 1s ease-out, stroke-width 1s cubic-bezier(0.405, 1.57, 0.45, 1.35), false false false, false false false, false false false;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 1s, 0s, 0s, 0s;
  -moz-transition: stroke 1s ease-out false, stroke-width 1s cubic-bezier(0.405, 1.57, 0.45, 1.35) 1s, false false false false, false false false false, false false false false;
  -o-transition: stroke 1s ease-out false, stroke-width 1s cubic-bezier(0.405, 1.57, 0.45, 1.35) 1s, false false false false, false false false false, false false false false;
  transition: stroke 1s ease-out, stroke-width 1s cubic-bezier(0.405, 1.57, 0.45, 1.35) 1s, false, false, false;
}
```